# Labels colors in Bio.Phylo

Tags: python, biopython, phylogeny

I am trying to familiarize with Biopython for phylogenetics with the official documentation.
https://biopython-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/13%20-%20Phylogenetics%20with%20Bio.Phylo.html

Using the code below, I have plotted a phylogenetic tree.

```
from io import StringIO
from Bio import Phylo
from Bio.Phylo.Applications import PhymlCommandline
from Bio.Phylo.PAML import codeml
from Bio.Phylo.PhyloXML import Phylogeny
%matplotlib inline

# Load IQtree tree file data:
tree = Phylo.read('example.phy.treefile', "newick")

# Input the tree name:
tree.name = 'Example phylogenetic tree'

# Draw the tree plot:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 18), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
Phylo.draw(tree, axes=ax)
```

Unfortunately the confidence levels on the axes are difficult to read, and I wish to change their colour to blue.
I have tried the different codes below to change the colour, but none is working.
Would anyone know the way to do it?

```
tree.branch_labels.color="blue"
tree.Clade.confidence.color = 'blue'
tree.Clade.color = 'blue'
Clade.confidence.color = 'blue'
```

Example file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t9kbd2ySn_B2rkgf5aJ-dgUBcCTFJ3PN/view?usp=sharing
Tree plot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S774FWaSzIIRU-EPdt2MAJTWIrQEMiOe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is impossible in **Biopython** as it provides the minimum functionality for tree visualisation intentionally. The `draw` function has this block responsible for the representation of text over nodes & branches:

```py
label = label_func(clade)
if label not in (None, clade.__class__.__name__):
    axes.text(
        x_here,
        y_here,
        f" {label}",
        verticalalignment="center",
        color=get_label_color(label),
    )
# Add label above the branch (optional)
conf_label = format_branch_label(clade)
if conf_label:
    axes.text(
        0.5 * (x_start + x_here),
        y_here,
        conf_label,
        fontsize="small",
        horizontalalignment="center",
    )
```

As you may see, there is no way to specify colour or font size for `conf_label` (a text over a  branch). So there are only two ways: either to use R's `ggtree` or to make a patch of the `draw` function wherein you will put colour parameter or change fontsize.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `labels_colors` argument in the `Phylo.draw` function that accepts a function with the label as a parameter or a dictionary that checks association with the labels.`

```
Phylo.draw(tree, axes=ax, label_colors={x: 'red})
```